# C++ function accepting function pointer and non-static member function as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I built an interface taking pointers to functions. Sometimes this calculation depends on state, which I want to encapsulate in a class and pass its method:

```
#include <iostream>


class Printer {
public:
    static void print(int i) {  // Want to get rid of the static
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
};


template<typename int_func>
void with_1(int_func func) {
    func(1);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Printer printer;
    with_1(printer.print);
    return 0;
}
```

I need non-static methods (and would even prefer overloading `operator()`). However removing the static results in `error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`.

I could use a dummy like this:

```
Printer printer;
void dummy(int i) {
    printer.print(i);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    with_1(dummy);
    return 0;
}
```

But that does not look elegant to me. Can I write a template that accepts both, function pointers and non-static methods? Or is there even a better design pattern for my problem?

Comment: No. Because for a non-static methods you need an instance of the class... Why would you need to have such function? If your method does not need an instance of the class, makes it static, otherwize I don't see how you could have a function that could use both... ?

Comment: Look into `std::function`, lambdas, `std::bind`, and some combination of them.

Comment: You should be able to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Suggest adding `&` before taking address of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply pass non-static method like this, because they work on instance. A simply solution is to use lambda:

```
#include <iostream>


class Printer {
public:
    static void print(int i) {  // Want to get rid of the static
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
};


template<typename int_func>
void with_1(int_func func) {
    func(1);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Printer printer;

    // Can use capture by reference because we are sure printer still
    // exist during execution of with_1
    with_1([&printer](int i){ printer.print(i); });

    return 0;
}
```

[example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1af5254ab2a0a1df)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Printer printer;
    with_1( std::bind( &Printer::print, printer, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

(You'll need to `#include <functional>`.)

Comment: Actually I prefer to bind a pure function to some arguments over using some kind of functor, thanks for pointing out :-)